# How to validate time in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a value "27:30" as a varchar. I want to cast this value in time.
like.... CAST('27:30' AS Time) OR CONVERT('27:30', TIME).

But it gives error.

How can I convert it?

Comment: what time is `27:30`  supposed to be?

Comment: It means 27 hours and 30 minutes.

Comment: yes, but **what time is it**?, you know, in 24 hour day?, do you want it to be `03:30`?

Comment: 27:30 is not a TIME, you wont see it on a digital watch, its a custom duration string.  Why not take the 27 and multiply it by 60 then add 30 and store it as minutes in an int column.

Comment: You can not convert to time because it is not valid time. Maximum is 24 hours.

Comment: Actually I want   to do  "DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:00:00', CAST('27:30' AS TIME))"  . Any suggestion?

Comment: @MohammedAshrafali you are not understanding the `TIME` datatype. It's not supposed to store **any length** of time, it's to store the time of a single day. So, if you need to have 27 hours and 30 minutes, either store the minutes in an `INT` column, or you can add that length to a `DATETIME` column (where adding 27 hours will make the time go to the next day)

Comment: For what? is it supposed to represent duration? 27:30 is not a TIME value, it could be a timespan or duration. Anyways, you'll have to parse it manually.

Comment: If `DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:00:00', CAST('27:30' AS TIME))` worked it would return a _number_ not a _time_. Which implies that you need to should store this in a numeric field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Actually I want to do "DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:00:00', CAST('27:30' AS TIME))" . Any suggestion?

To convert your HH:MM string to minutes, which is what the above (invalid) expression tries to do:

```
SELECT 
   f, 
   CAST(SUBSTRING(f, 1, CHARINDEX(':', f, 1) - 1) AS INT) * 60 + SUBSTRING(f, CHARINDEX(':', f, 1) + 1, 2)
FROM 
   (VALUES ('00:00'),('15:10'),('27:30'),('3:00'),('1:1')) T(f)
```

For

```
00:00   0
15:10   910
27:30   1650
3:00    180
1:1     61
```

Answer (score -3):

Is your target column is datetime ? If so you do not need to convert but simply cast, alternatively use such thing as

select cast(columnname as datetime(0)) as datetime from your table

Comment: `cast` and `convert` are essentially the same operation. Furthermore, you can not cast/convert 27:30 to datetime, since datetime has a maximum value of 23 for the hour part.